# Is there a way to read an exact amount of split integers in C#?

Tags: c#

Basically I've got this code:

```
var inputData = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

int N = int.Parse(inputData[0]);
int K = int.Parse(inputData[1]);
int[] A = new int[N];
```

From the console I need to read N and K like this:

4 2

In order to input elements in the array 'A', I need to read elements like this:

45 50 47 46

I figured out how to read N and K , but to fill the array , if N is let's say 35 , I must read exactly 35 numbers from a single line , how do I do that?

---

I've tried Fabio's solution and the code turned out like this:

```
var inputData = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int N = int.Parse(inputData[0]);
            int K = int.Parse(inputData[1]);
            int[] A = new int[N];
            var elements = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Take(N).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                A[i] = Convert.ToInt32(elements[i]);
            }
```

That worked perfectly!

P.S
I am still trying to grasp StackOverflow's rules for asking question and formatting my questions so I'm sorry for leaving this huge chunk here and I want to thank everybody for reaching out.

Comment: If the line contains more than 35 numbers, do you ignore the extras?

Comment: You use a for cycle... The `Split()` will split any number of pieces, 2, 10, 20, 100, 200... It doesn't have a maximum number of supported pieces

Comment: Try something like `var values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' '); for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++) { A[i] = values[i]; }`. This assumes that the number of elements types matches the size of `A`.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Take(35).ToArray();`

Comment: @Fabio: Good one.

Comment: This won't matter unless you are doing this like millions of times per second or so. The answers in the comments above are fine for simple use but if for example you want only 35 numbers and are splitting 1000 then it makes more sense for you to do the split yourself in a while/for loop for performance (memory, computation) reasons.

Comment: Can just call `Split()`, btw - whitespace is the default delimiter

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are all on a single line (e.g., N, then K, then all the array values), you can do this:

```
var inputData = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

int N = int.Parse(inputData[0]);
int K = int.Parse(inputData[1]);
int[] A = inputData.Skip(2).Take(N).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

If the values for the array A are on a separate line, you can do this:

```
var inputData = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ', 2);

int N = int.Parse(inputData[0]);
int K = int.Parse(inputData[1]);
int[] A = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ', N).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: The way I interpreted the question, the number of elements is given on one line, and the actual elements are given on a second line.  So, I think the `.Skip(2)` isn't needed, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll read the first line, to get the size of the array, then read another line. You didn't say what you do with K.. maybe it's the number of lines of N elements..

```
var inputData = Console.ReadLine().Split();

int N = int.Parse(inputData[0]);
int K = int.Parse(inputData[1]);

var inputs = new List<int[]>();

for(k = 0; k < K; k++){
    Console.Write($"Enter {N} numbers separated by spaces: ");
    inputData = Console.ReadLine();
    var bits = inputData.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if(bits.Length == N)
      inputs.Add(bits); //they did put N entries, woot
    else
      k--;              //make them do it again
}
```